# How to create a custom legend table using the colors from the chart in Crystal Reports?

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

As a requirement of the project, we need to draw a bar graph/chart on one of the reports and display another grid below it, with all the x-axis elements in the chart, similar to a legend but with additional information. The first column in the grid would have the color labels along with the titles, followed by other columns for the additional data.

I am currently in the boot camp round with Crystal Reports and do not have an in-depth knowledge on it. I have tried to explore various options under chart expert etc. but do not seem to be getting anywhere with it. can you please point me towards the correct direction and help me accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use CR and only found out you can't control the colors used, which sucks, big time.

So where i could i extracted the colors from a generated report and used custom boxes with those colors. Ofcourse that doesn't work if the amount of columns are variable.

If you're lucky CR uses the same colors everytime so you could maybe generate a report with the maximum columns and use those colors programmatically.

If anyone has a better solution i sure love to hear it.